# How to deal with non-respect of payment-terms?

Tags: contracts, payment-terms, payments, late-payment, information-technology

I'm working as a Freelance for 2 months (4 months remaining).

The contract between my headhunter and me mentions 3 entities:

- My own company
- Headhunter's company
- End client's company

I just learnt (two months later!) that there's another entity in the chain:

- My own company
- Headhunter's company
- **Another company charging to transmit end client's money to my Headhunter.**
- End client's company

They didn't told me it!

The issue now is that this "new" intermediary doesn't want to pay my headhunter in time (some conflicts between them apparently).

So my headhunter wants to pay me **more than 60 days** after receipt of my invoice **instead of 30 maximum** as mentioned explicitly by my contract. 
For instance, for January, I sent my invoice the 31th, so I expected to be pay the **3rd March**. They want to pay the **7th April**.

> *"We don't have money now, sorry, and sorry again, you would have to wait 60 days instead of 30 for each of your invoices"*.

What is a good way to solve this kind of severe issue?
I just lost any confidence with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered your own question...

> as mentioned explicitly by my contract

You have it in your contract, you have both signed it, you have the upper hand. Demand payment by the due date, as per the contract. Remind them that failure to pay is breach of contract, the implications of this should be clear to them already.

Comment: Should I think about prosecuting them, since their "No" sounds non-negotiable? What would you do ...?